# Can I do some work after DialogFragment.dismiss()

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment and I have to show AlertDialog with some information after my dialog dismiss. Can I show AlertDialog after dismiss?
Her is my code:

```
 mContinueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("");
            StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder("");

            if (loginManager.resetPassword()){
                message.append(getString(R.string.reset_pass_succes));
                title.append(getString(R.string.caption_success));
            }else {
                message.append(loginManager.getLastError());
                title.append(getString(R.string.caption_error));
            }

            dismiss();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(title.toString())
                    .setMessage(message.toString())
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }
    });
```

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While it might not be a good practice, you can definitely show another dialog from your existing `AlertDialog`; just make sure that you show the new AlertDialog **before** you call `dismiss()` on the parent Dialog.

This is what the code might look like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(title.toString())
                    .setMessage(message.toString())
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    alertDialog.show()
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
```